# rm all files under a directory using python subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.4, rm

I'm writing a script that will move files into a .trash directory in a user's home folder. I want to add the ability to empty the trash directory by calling `rm -rf /home/user/.trash/*` using python's subprocess.call()

```
~$ touch file1
~$ trash file1
['mv', 'file1', '/home/rodney/.trash/']
~$ ls .trash
file1
~$ trash --empty
['rm', '-rf', '/home/rodney/.trash/*']
~$ ls .trash
file1
```

As you can see the rm command did not remove the contents of the trash. However if I execute the command directly on the command line it works.

```
~$ rm -rf /home/rodney/.trash/*
~$ ls .trash
~$
```

The output is from the following code

```
print(cmd)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

What is weird about this is if I exclude the * from the last argument in the cmd list then the subprocess call works but also removes the entire .trash directory. I do not want to delete the .trash directory; only everything under it.

To sum up the question

This works

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['rm', '-rf', '/home/rodney/.trash/'])
```

This does not

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['rm', '-rf', '/home/rodney/.trash/*'])
```

Why?

Comment: Why are you shelling out to `rm` to do something as simple as deleting files in python?

Comment: I thought it would be quicker to write rather than creating a file list and traversing all sub directories.

Comment: Perhaps, but it benefits you more in the long run to learn the APIs that Python has to offer. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31989328/119527).  Otherwise, you might as well just write this as a Bash script.

Comment: Note that `*` does *not* match files that begin with a dot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't shell out.

This uses [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to identify the files to be removed, and [`shutil.rmtree()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) to remove subdirectories.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, os.path
import glob
import shutil

def remove_thing(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        shutil.rmtree(path)
    else:
        os.remove(path)

def empty_directory(path):
    for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')):
        remove_thing(i)

empty_directory('trash')
```

**Example:**

```
$ tree trash/
trash/
├── aaa
├── bbb
├── ccc
├── ddd
└── sub
    ├── iii
    └── jjj

1 directory, 6 files

$ ./go.py 

$ tree trash/
trash/

0 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: use `os.path.join(path, '*')` instead of `path + '/*'`. Though `os.listdir(path)` might better express OP's *intent* (includes `.*` entries) than `glob`.

Comment: I had no idea it was this simple to do. I went ahead and implemented your suggestion. I wasn't aware that `*` doesn't match hidden files so I included @J.F.Sebastian's suggestion as well. For empty_directory I have `[remove(os.path.join(path, f)) for f in os.listdir(path)]` and everything works fine now.

Comment: Please don't use a list comprehension "just because" -- a normal `for` loop is Pythonic here. You're creating a `list` of `None` for every call to `remove` for no reason.

Comment: While neither shelling-out to `rm` nor using a list comprehension will be detrimental to the performance of your code, it's a very Good Idea to be thinking about the consequences of the code you write while you're learning.

Answer (score 4):

Shell expand `*` into file names. You need to pass `shell=True` keyword argument so that shell will interpret `*`.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('rm -rf /home/rodney/.trash/*', shell=True)
```

---

According to [`subprocess` - Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> If `shell` is True, the specified command will be executed through the
>   shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the
>   enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want
>   convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes,
>   filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~
>   to a user’s home directory. However, note that Python itself offers
>   implementations of many shell-like features (in particular, glob,
>   fnmatch, os.walk(), os.path.expandvars(), os.path.expanduser(), and
>   shutil).

Comment: Just tried this and now I get 'rm: missing operand' if I use a list. Joining the list managed to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: @Rodneyxr, I changed the code accordingly. Thank you for the feedback.